# Android Java Set Color to Color Variable

Tags: java, android, colors, integer

I'm trying to give my color variable a color, but I can't seem to get it working...

```
import android.graphics.Color;
Color mColor = Color.CYAN;
```

The error I get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Color
```

I don't understand why Color.CYAN is an integer? How can I put the color CYAN in my variable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color` isn't really an object. It has a public constructor, yes, but it has no member data nor instance methods. It's just a class with `static` methods to construct ARGB color `int` values. There are some ARGB `int`s predefined, such as `Color.CYAN`. So to use it, use an `int`:

```
int mColor = Color.CYAN;
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Comment: Ah, yes! I didn't know paint.setColor(int Color) used an int instead of Color, thanks! (I'll mark this as correct as soon as I can)